# Android OpenGL UV mapping error after triangulating

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, native

I'm building an Android app to render 3d (wavefront.obj) model. By using [tinyobjloader](https://github.com/syoyo/tinyobjloader/blob/master/tests/tester.cc), I can successfully load the model.

**Code:**

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
std::vector<glm::vec2> uvs;
std::vector<glm::vec3> normals;

tinyobj::attrib_t attrib;
std::vector<tinyobj::shape_t> shapes;
std::vector<tinyobj::material_t> materials;
for(size_t s =0; s < shapes.size(); s++)
    {
        size_t index_offset = 0;
        for(size_t f = 0; f < shapes[s].mesh.num_face_vertices.size(); f++)
        {
            int fv = shapes[s].mesh.num_face_vertices[f];
            for(size_t v = 0; v < fv; v++)
            {
                tinyobj::index_t idx = shapes[s].mesh.indices[index_offset + v];
                tinyobj::real_t vx = attrib.vertices[3*idx.vertex_index+0];
                tinyobj::real_t vy = attrib.vertices[3*idx.vertex_index+1];
                tinyobj::real_t vz = attrib.vertices[3*idx.vertex_index+2];
                tinyobj::real_t nx = attrib.normals[3*idx.normal_index+0];
                tinyobj::real_t ny = attrib.normals[3*idx.normal_index+1];
                tinyobj::real_t nz = attrib.normals[3*idx.normal_index+2];
                tinyobj::real_t ux = attrib.texcoords[2*idx.texcoord_index+0];
                tinyobj::real_t uy = attrib.texcoords[2*idx.texcoord_index+1];
                vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(vx,vy,vz));
                normals.push_back(glm::vec3(nx,ny,nz));
                uvs.push_back(glm::vec2(ux,uy));
            }
            index_offset += fv;
        }
    }
```

Because the original .obj file has multiple faces format, i.e:

```
f 1/2/3 3/2/1 3/2/3
f 1/2/3 1/3/4 1/4/5 6/7/2
```

so that I use Blender Triangulate with 'Beauty' option to convert quad to triangle. But the rendered result is weird [image: result]

I have built two function to initOpenGL (run once) and render().

**initOpenGL code:**

```
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);


glGenBuffers(1, &UVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, UVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvs.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &uvs[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//Linking Vertex Attribute
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

//bind texture
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, UVBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

//load texture
//texture1
glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
if(patternSrc1)
{

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, patWidth1, patHeight1, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 patternSrc1);
    //glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

**render() code:**

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

camera.ProcessOneFinger(moveStpX, moveStpY);
camera.ProcessTwoFinger(move2X, move2Y);
projection = glm::perspective(camera.GetZoom(), (GLfloat)600/(GLfloat)1024, nearPlane, farPlane);
view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
glm::mat4 model;
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
GLfloat angle = 20.0f;
model = glm::rotate(model, angle, glm::vec3( 1.0f, 0.3f, 0.5f));
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr( model ) );

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
```

**Model detail**

Texture:
[image]

Model.obj file after triangulated:

https://pastebin.com/vUjHv8Fr

Thank you!!!

Comment: Are you sure the coordinates are the problem? There seems to be a strange pattern on all windows.

Comment: @BDL Perhaps my code is the problem. Because I tried to map the UV on Blender and the result is ok!

Comment: @Rabbid76 The faces value is not real, just to reference. The actual value is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to me like your texture is upside down. There's basically two potential errors that could each lead to this happening. Most likely, the texture image itself is upside down, e.g., because the image data passed to `glTexImage2D()` is in the wrong order. Unlike most other APIs, OpenGL (by default) expects pixel data in row-wise order *starting from the bottom row*. Check the way you load the texture data to make sure it's in the right order.

If this is not the problem, then it might be that your texture coordinates are for a left-handed texture coordinate system. OpenGL, however, uses right-handed texture coordinates where the origin is the lower-left corner of the texture image rather than the upper left corner. I'm not a Blender guy, but there's probably an export setting for this…

Comment: Yah, just need to flip vertically and it's good to go. The result is OK now. Haha. Thank you